# Dynamic keyframe insertion not working on IE or Firefox

Tags: javascript, css

For my RPG game I have this Javascript function that adds keyframes to the header inside a style element. I was going to post my code into this text, but figured I would create a jsFiddle instead! Here it is:

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/qsdw6n0a/2/][1]
```

Click around anywhere on the page, and the ball shoots out from my character to where you clicked. This works by using css keyframes, but why is it only working **on chrome** and not Firefox, or Internet explorer?

Edit: Cannot seem to get the js fiddle to link correctly, hmm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your animation properties are prefixed with -webkit-, so they aren't going to work in non-webkit browsers (safari and chrome). Add the non-prefixed versions (animation-name, animation-duration) in addition to the prefixed ones.

Comment: Oh WOW! I totally forgot  to add them to the css class. I added the -webkit- prefix and the normal prefix to my keyframe variable and that confused me. Thank you!

Edit: Added `animation-name: shootright;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;` to the class, now works on firefox, ie sweet! (I'll mark you best answer in 3 minutes)